# Identifying and Non Identifying relationship

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have the following db structure and am wanting to add in a new table called notepad:

ClinicTable (Id PK)

PatientTable (Id PK, ClinicId PK FK)

DoctorTable (Id PK, ClinicId PK FK)

ConsultationTable( Id PK, ClinicId PK FK, PatientId FK, DoctorId FK)

- I'm waiting to hear back re: the business requirement, but the
  notepad could either be tied to the consultation (1 to 1) or tied to
  the patient (1 to M).
- We are slowly restructuring and refactoring as
  part of a new product build so I don't want to add the note to the
  consultation table - I'd prefer to store it separately
- A patient or consultation may or may not have a
  notepad record, but a notepad record cannot exist without a patient
  or a consultation.
- A notepad record will always be entered by a single doctor and cannot be owned 
  by any other doctor

How do I determine whether to make the relationships identifying or non-identifying?

All of the other tables have the clinic Id in them, but I don't see that I need that?

I'm thinking it should look like the following...

If the note is tied to the patient then I have:

NotepadTable (Id PK, PatientId  PK FK, DoctorId PK FK)

If the note is tied to the consultation then I have:

NotepadTable (Id PK, ConsultationId PK FK)

Comment: Before worrying about `NotepadTable`, you need to clarify your PKs for the other tables. Why is `ClinicId` part of the PK in `PatientTable`, `DoctorTable`, `ConsultationTable`? Can a patient not visit more than one clinic, and if they do, how will their data be recorded? Will `Id` be unique on its own or can different patients (or doctors) have the same `Id` value? Your `NotepadTable` continues the same weird approach to PKs, why?

Comment: Hi there, I couldn't agree more. Unfortunately, I've inherited the weird approach to PKs. Within the software, each practice is a completely isolated tenant with its own patient and doctor ids. Each table has an identity column as the Id. The same person will have two different patient ids at two different practices. The same doctors will have two different doctor ids at two different practices. Different patients can't have the same id. Can I at least make the relationship between notepad and consultation non-identifying?

Comment: Sounds like each table's PK should consist of just the `Id` column which means all relationships should be non-identifying once the design is fixed. In its current state you have non-identifying columns as part of your identifier, so a solid answer is difficult.

Comment: Business requirement is that the notepad belongs to the patient but is visible and editable alongside the consultation note as a widget on the same screen. When the read only flag on the consultation table is set to true 24 hours after it is written, the patient note also needs to be marked read only. Is it permissible to set a non-identifying relationship between patient and notepad and simply hold the consultid in the notepad table without creating a FK constraint?

Comment: FK constraints are just useful integrity mechanisms to help you maintain data consistency. Whether you use them or not is up to you.